# Get the points from a MatLab fit object plot

Tags: matlab, model-fitting

I am a Matlab amateur so please bear with me -

I currently use Matlab to fit a complex equation to two-dimensional data. Right now I have a program which uses `f = fit(xdata, ydata, function, options)` to generate a fit object.

I can then use `confint(f)` and `f.parameter` etc. to get the fitted coefficients and confidence intervals, and I can use `plot(f,x,y)` to make a plot of the data and the fit.

From that point on the only way I know how to get the points which were plotted is to use the brush(?) tool and select all of the line, then copy the data to clipboard and paste it into excel or some such thing. I would much rather get those points directly from Matlab, perhaps into an array, but I have no idea how.

Can any MatLab veteran tell me if what I want is even possible? It would be very difficult due to the complexity of my equation to plot those points myself, but I will if need be (it can take ~30 minutes to do this fit and my computer is no slouch).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not shared any code or data, I use an example from MATLAB documentation:

```
load franke
f = fit([x, y],z,'poly23');
plot(f,[x,y],z)
```

So as you can sew, it first loads a dataset including `x,y,z` vectors. Then fits a surface to the data using 'poly23'. In your case it can be different sets of vectors and function and still as you said you will get the `f` function.

Now we can take a look at the function `f`

```
>> f

     Linear model Poly23:
     f(x,y) = p00 + p10*x + p01*y + p20*x^2 + p11*x*y + p02*y^2 + p21*x^2*y 
                    + p12*x*y^2 + p03*y^3
     Coefficients (with 95% confidence bounds):
       p00 =       1.118  (0.9149, 1.321)
       p10 =  -0.0002941  (-0.000502, -8.623e-05)
       p01 =       1.533  (0.7032, 2.364)
       p20 =  -1.966e-08  (-7.084e-08, 3.152e-08)
       p11 =   0.0003427  (-0.0001009, 0.0007863)
       p02 =      -6.951  (-8.421, -5.481)
       p21 =   9.563e-08  (6.276e-09, 1.85e-07)
       p12 =  -0.0004401  (-0.0007082, -0.0001721)
       p03 =       4.999  (4.082, 5.917)
```

[image]

It shows you the form of the function and the coefficients. So you can use it as follows:

```
zz = f(x,y);
```

To make sure you can plot the data again:

```
figure;
scatter3(x,y,zz,'.k');
hold on
scatter3(x,y,z,'.');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you call `f = fit(xdata, ydata, function, options)`, **function** name decides the equation. See [list of official equations](https://in.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/list-of-library-models-for-curve-and-surface-fitting.html#btbcvnl).

Simply iterate through data points and compute results using corresponding polynomial. So in your case lets say if **function=poly2** you'll be doing computation as follows:

```
#Fit your data
f = fit([xdata, ydata],'poly2');

#Print name of coefficients (Just for Verification)
coeffnames(f)

#Fetch values of coefficients like p1, p2, ...
p = coeffvalues(c) 

#Compute output points from min(xdata) to max(xdata) spaced at deltaX
deltaX = 0.1;
x = [min(xdata):deltaX:max(xdata)];
Y = p(1)*x^2+p(2)*x+p(3);            #This is equation for function
```

I understand there can be alternate complex Java code to iterate through objects on a *matlab figure* and plot its value but using equations is a quick and valid approach.